# Can you identify what the sharp spikes in our data could be?

Tags: data-visualization, dataset, trend

Scenario: There was an online competition to win a prize. The competitors are technology start-up companies and the prize is worth around 5,000 USD.

There was a public, online vote to decide the overall winner. Competitors turned to social media to get the word out about their competition entry.

Prior to the public vote an expert panel decided which of the companies involved would make the short list. Those that made it to the short list are included in the public vote.

An interactive plot of 48 hours of the voting data collected between companies A, B, and C is available here: http://doge.bike/plot/. The source data is available here: http://doge.bike/plot/question.csv. At the beginning of this 48 hour period voting had been open for 8 days and everyone started at 0 votes.

Can you see any unusual/unexpected trends in the data? We were surprised to see the sharp spikes in the B and C lines. We thought it was odd that such large spikes would happen and then immediately stop, rather than tailing off slowly.

[image: Static image of plot]

Comment: Is this for a course?

Comment: @gung It's not for a course, this is a real public vote and we're trying to analyse the trends that we saw in the data.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your input, sorry I wasn't clear to start with. The y-axis is time beginning at midnight and lasting for 48 hours. The x-axis is cumulative number of votes.

Comment: @whuber Is it clearer now what kind of answer/information I'm looking for? Would very much appreciate the community being able to have a go at this.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick explanations. It's unclear how this is a statistical question, though: it seems to ask us to speculate about the observed behavior. Sure, like you we can look at the data and say yes, you do indeed have sharp increases followed by plateaus.  But that does not represent any advance over what you have already found out.  Any *explanation* would have to come from theories about crowd voting.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for taking the question off hold. I posted here hoping that someone would be able to provide some means of statistically measuring the significance of the sharp increases followed by the plateaus. Is this the correct place to ask a question about crowd voting theory?

Comment: We're not a site about particular subject matter or theories. Without positing a particular model of crowd voting, it's not going to be possible to attach any measure of "significance" to the patterns you think you see.  Here, you can get good advice on ways to explore these data and some cautions about how to avoid over-interpreting them. We can share ways to identify and quantify the magnitudes of spikes and plateaus and other such things. But if you're hoping for a statistical demonstration that there's something wrong or "unexpected" here, I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at votes per time interval may be helpful in highlighting the spikes, though it will still be difficult to model because some spikiness will be a natural result of particular social events like tweets from interested parties.

[image]

Distribution of the votes per 10 minute interval (A, B, C) emphasizes how A is different from the others:
[image]

Zooming in on the big spike for C with the minute-by-minute votes, it's interesting that every minute has between 1 and 3 votes.

[image]

Of course, it's really interesting that the final vote was so close. Were voters aware of the running totals?

Comment: Thank you for your already very insightful answer, very much appreciated. Voters were aware of the running totals, yes. Would be very interested to know how that might affect your analysis/conclusions.